# How does emit() knows which SLOT to use in PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

in main.py

```
def setNumberFormat2(self):
    dialog = numberformatdlg2.NumberFormatDlg(self.format, self)
    self.connect(dialog, SIGNAL("changed"), self.refreshTable)
    dialog.show()
```

and in `form.py`:

```
class NumberFormatDlg(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, format, parent=None):
       .....
     self.connect(buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Apply),
                                  SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.apply)
     self.connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL("rejected()"),
                                  self, SLOT("reject()"))
     self.setWindowTitle("Set Number Format (Modeless)")


  def apply(self):
     ....
     self.emit(SIGNAL("changed"))
```

According to the author:

> Finally, we emit a changed signal, and as we have seen, this causes
>   the caller’s refreshTable() method to be called, which in turn formats
>   all the numbers in the table using the caller’s format dictionary.

When we emit, how does it know we which SLOT we want to apply? Essentially, if we have

```
self.connect(dialog, SIGNAL("changed"), self.refreshTable)
self.connect(dialog, SIGNAL("changed"), self.anotherMethod)
```

How does `self.emit(...)` know which slot we are applying? or am I missing some information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.emit` doesn't "know" anything - it just fires the signal.
The `self.connect()` method is catching the signal and running the given function with the signal parameters.

If you connect two functions to a signal, I think that both will run.
You probably shouldn't do it, because it'll make your code a bit unreadable.

- If you want to run two functions, create a function that is called
  `changed_signal` that will call the other functions.
- If you want to run different functions for different uses, just fire different signals.

Comment: Mostly correct. Signal/Slot connection is done by the event loop. `connect()` method just informs the event loop about connections. It doesn't *run* the function, event loop does. Connecting a signal to two slots is fine. And both of them would be called when the signal is emitted. I don't see why that would be unreadable. The only gotcha is that, there is no guarantee to the execution order  of these functions. So one shouldn't rely on the other.

Comment: I believe that when programming with slots and signals, you should have use no more than one function for each signal. Why? Because I think it's more readable to remember that you have exactly one method connected to each signal. You won't have to bother and search the whole GUI code for another connect call that could be made for the same signal.

Comment: @Avaris Right. That puzzles me too because it doesn't guarantee the order. Thanks.

Comment: @iTayb: Well, most logical thing for `connect` calls is clustering them right after the instantiation of the relevant object. So that you won't be really "searching" them. You don't scatter those `connect` calls around, do you? :)

Comment: @Avaris Well, I guess you're right. It's a question of taste.

Comment: @Avaris The order was arbitrary, but since Qt 4.6, the slots are called in the order in which the connections were made (see the [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals) ).

Comment: @alexisdm: Thanks. I didn't noticed the change. This is good.